# How can I publish an updated version of an AppInventor app when forced to use a new / different certificate/key?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, app-inventor

I dabbled with AppInventor a year ago and built an app that I now need to update on the Google Play marketplace.

Im NOW using Flex/FlashBuilder4.6 now and I have the new version of the app all tested and good to go but android developer console shows message stating that It has to be done with the same key...

is there any type of work around here or am I really going to have to just abandon that previous app and re-create a new app entry on Google Play?

I setup a new MIT account when it moved and can see a few test projects in the MIT App Invetor but dont see the app in question so perhaps that all of this is futile.  I'll begin thinking I could setup the OLD app to show a message and then link that takes the user to the new app prole on google play but not having the zip file is a deal-breaker... any way around this at all?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

The question is: did you create the apk file with App Inventor only (possible since Version 125, May, 6 2012) or did you use another tool like Marketizer or AppToMarket to sign the app?

In case you used App Inventor only, you could use the same package name of the old project.
The package name for an App Inventor project looks like that:
 the first part of the package name is always the same for App Inventor projects **appinventor.ai_** then follows your **gmail login name** and then after the **.** follows the **App Inventor project name**
example: appinventor.ai_taifunbaer.caturday

For signing the app you can use the alias=**androidkey** and key pwd=**android**, see also [here](http://androidhelpcenter.blogspot.in/2012/06/app-inventor-apk-file-doesns-update-in.html)

Comment: thanks, that got me closer at least... after updating the package and app name in flashbuilder and creating the APK file I no longer got that same error -- but a new one that says the apk isnt zip aligned... so I recalled that I used to use app2market and downloaded that... but after entering all my info and trying to generate the final file, it just hangs and never finished anything at all...   I'll give it a little more thought this evening and will decide in the AM whether or not to just unpublish this version and launch a new, separate app on the marketplace.  thanks for the help.

Comment: If you used AppToMarket you also used a keystore which most probably was different than the default alias and pwd... Without that keystore it is impossible to update your existing app in Google Play.